# Cron Job is Scheduling to Run Every Minute Instead of Once Daily

Tags: wordpress

I have created some code that runs a cron job to see if the expiry date I assigned to my post (custom field) is met. If so, it changes the status to "Draft".

I've done something wrong with my schedule as the cron job is queuing up every minute and I thought I assigned it to run once a day.

Any help much appreciated.

```
   function cronstarter_activation() 
    {
       if( !wp_next_scheduled("katie-posts-cron-job")) 
       {  
            wp_schedule_event (time(), "daily", "katie-posts-cronjob");  
       }
    }
    add_action("wp", "cronstarter_activation");

    function cronstarter_deactivate() 
    {   
       $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled ("katie-posts-cronjob");
       wp_unschedule_event ($timestamp, "katie-posts-cronjob");
    } 
    register_deactivation_hook (__FILE__, "cronstarter_deactivate");

function cron_add_timer($schedules) 
{
    $schedules["everyday"] = array(
        'interval' => 86400,
        'display' => __("Once a Day")
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter("cron_schedules", "cron_add_timer");


    function prfx_custom_meta() 
    {
        add_meta_box ("prfx_meta", __("katie Posts", "prfx-textdomain"), "prfx_meta_callback", "post", "normal", "high");
    }
    add_action ("add_meta_boxes", "prfx_custom_meta");

    function prfx_admin_styles()
    {
        global $typenow;

        if ($typenow == "post") 
       {
            wp_enqueue_style ("prfx_meta_box_styles", plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . "/css/meta-box-styles.css");
        }
    }
    add_action ("admin_print_styles", "prfx_admin_styles");

    function prfx_meta_callback($post) 
    {
        wp_nonce_field (basename( __FILE__ ), "prfx_nonce");
        $prfx_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
        ?>

        <p>
        <label for="meta-text" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e("Post Expiry Date: ", "prfx-textdomain")?></label>
        <input type="date" name="meta-text" id="meta-text" value="<?php if (isset ($prfx_stored_meta["meta-text"])) echo $prfx_stored_meta["meta-text"][0]; ?>" />
        </p>

        <?php
    }

    function prfx_meta_save($post_id) 
    {
        $is_autosave      = wp_is_post_autosave($post_id);
        $is_revision        = wp_is_post_revision($post_id);
        $is_valid_nonce = (isset( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

        if ($is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce) 
        {
            return;
        }

        if (isset($_POST["meta-text"])) 
        {
            update_post_meta($post_id, "meta-text", sanitize_text_field($_POST["meta-text"]));
        }
    }
    add_action ("save_post", "prfx_meta_save");

    function katie_expired_posts()
    {
        $args           = array ("post_type" => "post", "post_status" => "publish");
        $post_query = new WP_Query($args);

       if ($post_query->have_posts()) 
       {
        while($post_query->have_posts() ) 
        {
            $post_query->the_post();
                         $sExpiry = get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), "meta-text", true);
            $sToday = date("Y-m-d");

            if ( ($sExpiry <= $sToday) && ($sExpiry != "" ) )
            {
               $my_post = array ("ID" => get_the_ID(), "post_status"  => "Draft",);
               wp_update_post ($my_post);          
            }
        }
       }
    }
    add_action ("katie-posts-cronjob", "katie_expired_posts");
```

Comment: Please post the actual code, not an image of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schedule naming is not correct.

See:

```
function cronstarter_activation() 
{
  if( !wp_next_scheduled("katie-posts-cron-job")) // <--- cron-job
  {  
    wp_schedule_event (time(), "daily", "katie-posts-cronjob"); // <--- cronjob 
  }
}
```

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: If you run this in for example `functions.php` with the hook `add_action("wp", "cronstarter_activation");`. It will auto run?

Comment: Please read WP docs when you develop in WP. See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/. In the first line it states you need to visit the site to trigger `wp_schedule_event()`. Setup a cronjob in your hosting environment if you don't want to be site-visit dependent.